# Why can't I get external links to be nofollow?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve 2 things:

1) I want to make all external links on my page open up in a new tab

2) At the same time I want all such links to be nofollow.

With the code attached below, I am able to achieve 1) but I can't seem to get 2) to work

```
if (document.readyState != 'loading') {
    fn();
  } else if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  } else {
    document.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', function() {
      if (document.readyState != 'loading')
        fn();
    });
  }
}

ready(function() {

  var website = window.location.hostname;

  var internalLinkRegex = new RegExp('^((((http:\\/\\/|https:\\/\\/)(www\\.)?)?'
                                     + website
                                     + ')|(localhost:\\d{4})|(\\/.*))(\\/.*)?$', '');

  var anchorEls = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  var anchorElsLength = anchorEls.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < anchorElsLength; i++) {
    var anchorEl = anchorEls[i];
    var href = anchorEl.getAttribute('href');

    if (!internalLinkRegex.test(href)) {
      anchorEl.setAttribute('target', '_blank', 'rel','nofollow');
    }
  }
});
```

I would like all external links on my website to open in external windows and be nofollow. Also, I would like to stick to using Javascript.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think `setAttribute` support passing multiple name-value paris according to this https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute. Do you try `anchorEl.setAttribute('target', '_blank');` then `anchorEl.setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow')` ?

Comment: @SolomonTam hey that worked! Thanks. If it helps you, feel free to copy and paste it to the answer section below and I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) MDN web dosc, `setAttribute()` only accept one name and one value.

So instead of

```
anchorEl.setAttribute('target', '_blank', 'rel','nofollow');
```

try this

```
anchorEl.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
anchorEl.setAttribute('rel','nofollow');
```